# Where do unopened packs go?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

I bought the Big Box 14 pack deal and opened 4-5 of the packs. Before I finished opening the rest I had to do some other things on my phone. When I came back to the game, I couldn't find out how to open the rest of the packs. It doesn't appear that 9-10 packs worth of cards I haven't seen are in my card inventory, but I do see cards from the packs I opened.

How do I see & open my unopened packs?

Comment: Remember the bounty you currently have up! If the accepted answer explains it right, feel free to reward it the bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Once a pack is purchased and the process of opening it has been initiated, if the player exits the process than all cards will be automatically rewarded.

[source](https://d3go.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=36817#p467206) - quote from a response to a support ticket someone opened.

Comment: Ok, I guess this true because from ten unopened packs in a big box there a couple of green cards I don't recognise (haven't played other colors), but that is really really disappointing. Opening new packs is about the most enjoyable aspect in any ccg.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram yea I agree it is a lot of fun opening packs. At least you still got the cards though.